# AWS EC2 /bin/php not executing php script

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-php-sdk

I am using AWS EC2 linux2 and trying to run my php script from command line console :

I have my files in folder `/var/www/html/myfolder/test.php`

test.php

```
<?php
require ('./functionfile.php');
echo  'hello';
?>
```

I have functionfile.php in that same folder.

when i try to run with `/bin/php /var/www/html/myfolder/test.php` then it gives me an error

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/myfolder/test.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required './functionfile.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/myfolder/test.php on line 2
```

When i directly run this file using http://my-public-dns.com/myfolder/test.php then it works but not working from command line.

Comment: Relative paths are relative to your current working directory, not the location of the file being executed.

Comment: Ok. so do i have to give absolute path ?

Comment: do a chdir() before requiring functionfile.php